# ¿Como obtengo el contexto de mi tabla en C# mediante entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Actualmente estoy usando entity framework 5, y lo que quiero hacer son consultas, inserciones, actualizaciones mediante entity framework. ya traspase mi BD hacia un archivo .edmx de coneccion en .NET. Mi problema actual es que quiero hacer una inserción de prueba, pero según lo que eh leído necesito un contexto como tal, pero no se como obtener ese contexto para tener acceso a mis tablas de entity.

Código actual:

```
 Context.UploadExcel.Add(Excel); ----- context no contiene definicion de 
                                        UploadExcel
```

El problema sigue siendo el mismo que no reconoce a mis tablas en el contexto y necesito llegar a ellas para manipularlas.

Comment: aquí un artículo que te puede ayudar, es algo extenso pero te puede servir https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

Comment: Lo que quieres es usar un archivo de excel como repositorio y conectarte a el con EF, verdad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el nombre de tu contexto los puedes encontrar en:

> **Web.config** / **connectionStrings** / **nombre de tu conexión**

**O**

> Expande el **Model.edmx** / Expande el **Model.Context.tt** / Abre el archivo
>   **Model.Context.cs** y en el **constructor** de la clase está el nombre.

Saludos.